# Group pages in wagtail

Tags: wagtail

how can i group pages in wagtail cms?

I have a page model for cities in my project. Accessible throw /cityname/:

- www.example.com/london/
- www.example.com/berlin/
- www.example.com/newyork/
- ...

After having hundrets of cities in my database, my root view in wagtail cms got unclear. I would like to group all cities, how can i do this?

Usually you would create a parent object, but in this case my parent is the root. Can I create somehow a virtual parent page?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a virtual parent page from within the Explorer section of the admin, you can only (currently) navigate/manage pages within their native tree structure.

However, you may want to use [`modeladmin`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html) to provide a separate section of the admin dedicated to editing the city pages. Using `modelAdmin` also lets you hide the city page type from the Explorer section and gives you lots of customisation on how pages are listed, searched and filtered.

Here is a slightly modified example from the docs.

```
# file: myapp/wagtail_hooks.py
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register)
from .models import CityPage


class CityPageModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = CityPage
    menu_label = 'Cities'  # ditch this to use verbose_name_plural from model
    menu_icon = 'grip'  # change as required
    menu_order = 200  # will put in 3rd place (000 being 1st, 100 2nd)
    add_to_settings_menu = False  # or True to add your model to the Settings sub-menu
    exclude_from_explorer = True # setting to true will exclude pages of this type from Wagtail's explorer view
    list_display = ('title', 'country', 'other_example_field', 'live')
    list_filter = ('live', 'country')
    search_fields = ('title',) # remember trailing comma on single item sets

# Now you just need to register your customised ModelAdmin class with Wagtail
modeladmin_register(CityPageModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Thank you, Is it possible to use the revision feature inhere? (The same as on normal Page objects?)

Comment: Yep. The editing interface is essentially the same as if it were accessed via the Explorer.

Comment: I checked the bakerydemo but I can not see the "Revision" function in the admin for the two modeladmin's; https://github.com/wagtail/bakerydemo/blob/master/bakerydemo/base/wagtail_hooks.py Do I have to activate it first? Did I something wrong?

Comment: In the bakerydemo - there are no Page models used in the modeladmin, and only Page models have revisions. I just did a test myself by setting up a BlogPageAdmin very similar to the answer code above and it all works as expected. When you click the item in the left side menu, you get taken to a list of Blog Pages (or city pages in the answer above). Click edit on any one and you are taken to the normal page edit view, with revisions accessible at the bottom right. If you are referring to the the ability to click the 'more' dropdown that has 'move/copy/delete/revisions' this is **not** available

Comment: With a page object it works perfectly! But there is one last problem => I use this approach for a multilingual website: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/advanced_topics/i18n/duplicate_tree.html
I would like to select first the website and afterwards I want to add my "CityPages". So what I want is: Click first on my separate section. Then I get a list of my website (en/; de/, pl/...) and afterwards I want add a CityPage. How can I do this?

Comment: I am not sure on the best way to do that sorry - I have not done i18n and do not know how the your models are structured for this. Maybe you could use the `list_filter` attribute by adding the language to the filter (this will then appear on the right hand side in the page listing). Or you could use ModelAdminGroup and create a ModelAdmin for each language's model. It might be best to ask a new question about using ModelAdmin to manage multiple language pages (put in your page model code also).

Comment: Creating a ModelAdmin for every language/site requires to add programmatically new languages. This is not really what I want... Any other idea :)?

Answer (score 0):

There are no such thing as a virtual parent page in Wagtail and I'm not sure whether you want all the cities pages to go under a single parent of have multiple parent (e.g. grouping cities by country or something). I'll assume the later but let me know if that's not the case and I'll update the answer.

So you have a few options here:

1) Create a `CountryPage` as a child of the `Homepage` and under which live all the `CityPage`. Then you accept that the url will be `/france/paris/`.

2) Create a `CountryPage` as a child of the `Homepage` and under which live all the `CityPage` (same as option 1), but you also make the `Homepage` a [RoutablePage](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/routablepage.html) which will serve the content of the cities pages.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtail.contrib.wagtailroutablepage.models import RoutablePageMixin, route


class Homepage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    @route(r'^(\w+)/$', name='city')
    def city(self, request, city_slug):
        city = get_object_or_404(CityPage, slug=city_slug)
        return city.serve(request)
```

However this has some caveats:
- The `CityPage` is still available at `/france/paris/` so you'll need to setup the canonical URL to make sure there is no double indexing.
- The `CountryPage` is still available at `/france/` which you might not want.
- The names might clash. For example, if you have a `CountryPage` with a slug of `luxembourg` with a `CityPage` of with the same slug as a child. When you'll visit `/luxembourg/` you would expect the `Homepage` to pick it up and server `/luxembourg/luxembourg/` but it won't because the URL will be picked up by the `CountryPage` at `/luxembourg/` already.

3) If your cities don't necessarily need to be a page (they are more data holder than anything else and don't have children), you could convert them to a model. This model would be exposed in the admin interface as [snippets](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/topics/snippets.html) or [modeladmin](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html) and served by the `Homepage` (similarly to option 2).

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtail.contrib.wagtailroutablepage.models import RoutablePageMixin, route


class Homepage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    @route(r'^(\w+)/$', name='city')
    def city(self, request, city_slug):
        city = get_object_or_404(CityModel, slug=city_slug)

        context = self.get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['city'] = city

        return render(request, 'city.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you. Point 3 doesn't work for me, because I use a multilingual site with this approach: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/advanced_topics/i18n/duplicate_tree.html (I need to group them by sites somehow ...)
Point 1 is not an option and I would like to use point 2 but why is it not possible to just override the page url? Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Another way is to use solution 1 and do the magic with mod_rewrite, but this is not really what I want. Why is it so hard to overwrite the url?

Comment: In option 2, it isn't possible to overwrite the URL because that's the order Wagtail uses for URL resolution. It first check for real pages and then for "virtual" pages.

The reason it's "so hard to overwrite the url" is simply because Wagtail hasn't been built to solve such problem. The source of truth in Wagtail is the tree so trying to create pages at a given path on the tree but serves them on a different path is working against Wagtail's philosophy.

Comment: I used option 1) and limited the access via .htaccess and wrote my own django view with url to present this specific page. There is one last problem ... How can I stop wagtail adding this pages to the sitemap?

Comment: Solved this problem as described here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/sitemaps.html => Customising!
How can I override the "live link" in wagtail. It is leading to blocked url and not to my own created ...