# Is it bad practice to create wagtail page only for organizational purposes?

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I am in the process of migrating an existing Django app for a news website over to Wagtail.

The first part of this migration will be porting all of the existing articles, that exist as Django models, over to Wagtail Pages.

Along with this, we will have separate Wagtail Page types for website pages such as terms and conditions, privacy policy, etc.

My question is the following, when looking that the Wagtail admin, it is clear that the articles need to be nested beneath a parent page for organizational purposes, otherwise all of the article pages will live amongst unrelated pages such as terms and conditions, privacy policy, etc...

I have thus created a basic Page which is used only for organizational purposes, it is the parent for all Articles and lives at the HomePage level.

```
class ArticleListing(Page):
    """A page meant for organizational purposes. All articles live under this page."""
    max_count = 1
    parent_page_types = ['news.HomePage']
    subpage_types = ['news.Article']
```

The problem is that in order to register this page, it is given a url path. I do not want to return anything from this page at all, the url related to it should throw a 404. What should I do here? I am thinking about overriding the route method to return a 404.

Is this a perversion of the Wagtail framework? If so how exactly am I supposed to organize my content within the Wagtail admin without having a giant mix of unrelated pages with no organization?

This same problem thus applies to the HomePage model I am using, which again is purely for organizational purposes at this stage in the migration.

```
class Index(Page):
    max_count = 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group pages in wagtail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287247/group-pages-in-wagtail)

Answer (score 1):

We created a page type we called "MenuOnlyPage" so that people could add sections to their site without having to have content for the section index page. I don't love it but it is pretty popular.

```
class MenuOnlyPage(BasePage):
"""
This page exists purely to be a parent of other pages.  It has no content of its own, and the menu
behaves differently for these pages.

Rather than acting like a normal page, MenuOnlyPages always redirect to / if browsed to.
"""

###################
# EDIT FORM CONFIG
###################
content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
]

settings_panels = [
    MultiFieldPanel(
        heading='Page Settings',
        children=[
            FieldPanel('slug', widget=SlugInput),
            FieldPanel('nav_title'),
            FieldPanel('breadcrumb_title'),
            FieldPanel('show_in_menus'),
        ]
    )
]

publishing_panels = [
    PublishingPanel()
]

edit_handler = TabbedInterface(
    base_form_class=ShowInMenusByDefaultForm,
    children=[
        ObjectList(content_panels, heading='Content'),
        ObjectList(settings_panels, heading='Settings', classname='settings'),
        ObjectList(publishing_panels, heading='Publishing'),
    ]
)

# This should not appear in the search index.
search_fields = []

# This attribute is what the template code looks for to detect a MenuOnlyPage. Since only the template code cares
# about the difference, this is the easiest way to do it.
menu_only = True

page_description = 'Creates an entry in the Menu that exists only to be the parent of other Pages in the menu.'

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Menu-only Page'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Menu-only Pages'

def get_sitemap_urls(self, request=None):
    """
    Excludes all MenuOnlyPages from the XML Sitemap.
    """
    return []

@property
def preview_modes(self):
    """
    Disable previewing of MenuOnlyPages, since they don't have anything to preview.
    """
    return []

@property
def is_linkable(self):
    """
    Our breadcrumbs template uses this to know whether or not to create a link to this page.
    """
    return False

def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Rather than acting like a normal page, MenuOnlyPages always redirect to the homepage if browsed to.
    """
    # A user being able to visit one of these pages at all is a fluke, so we don't want to accidentally cache a
    # permanent redirect into their browser if they do manage to hit this code.
    response = redirect('/')
    return self.add_cache_control_headers(response)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is along the lines of what I am looking for. Suppose the pages in question are for news articles. Could you explain what I am losing out on by going with a model as opposed to a page?  I understand that I will not be able to leverage the tree type organization of pages, but this is not something that is advantageous to me. What critical wagtail features would I be missing out on, if any? It seems that I can achieve the same thing through Django models and not have to have this pass through object which increases technical debt.

Comment: I don't understand "by going with a model as opposed to a page". Nothing in this discussion suggested not using Page subclasses for your news articles. My suggestion was only about how to create the parent page that was only for organization.  For my news section, I have a NewsIndexPage that is a real page and shows the 10 most recent articles. And then NewsPages all live under the NewsIndexPage. Roughly like the blog example in https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html#a-basic-blog

Comment: When you say "Django models" do you mean using the Snippets models? Those are largely regular Django models that you can edit via the Wagtail admin. There has been a lot of recent work to add many Page features to Snippets so the main ones you would be missing if you didn't use a Page subclass would be commenting and each instance automatically having its own URL. You could fix the url issue by creating your own routing + own serve view. But it feels to me like news articles really should be pages.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the serve method to raise a 404 error. This way, when someone tries to access the URL associated with that page, a 404 response will be returned.

```
from django.http import Http404

class ArticleListing(Page):
    max_count = 1
    parent_page_types = ['news.HomePage']
    subpage_types = ['news.Article']

    def serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        raise Http404
```